# MystIIQ video converter having problems with mpv files

Tags: 20.04, mp4, video-conversion

I have been using MystIQ video converter with great success in Ubuntu 20.04, but it seems to have problems with MPV files.  There is no audio mostly.   Some MPV files are OK, but mostly they get converted to MP4 and have no audio. Do you have any ideas?